# jQuery Validating Australian Phone Numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation, formatting

I am trying to get the value from an input box, validate & format the number, then update the input field.

I want it to validate all Australian phone numbers (mobile and landline)
formatting mobile numbers to 
04XX XXX XXX
and Landline numbers to 
(0X) XXXX XXXX

```
var phone_number = $("#phone").val();
//validate mobile number
var formatted = phone_number.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '$1-$2-$3');
//replace number
$("#phone").val(formatted);
```

Any help would be awesome :)

Comment: Hey Nick just wondering if you manage to find a way around this ? I am hoping to be able to find a jQuery based solution for this.

Comment: I ended up implementing the function I posted below... Like said below, not optimal, but not worth spending anymore time on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same regex/replace logic you have suggested.

## html

```
Mobile:<input id = "mobile" type = "tel" maxlength=8></input>
Landline:<input id = "landline" type = "tel" maxlength=10></input>
```

## jquery

```
$("#mobile").blur(function(){
    var mobile_ele = $("#mobile");
    var mobileNum = mobile_ele.val();
    var formattedNum = mobileNum.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{3})/g,"04$1 $2 $3");
    mobile_ele.val(formattedNum);
});
$("#landline").blur(function(){
    var landline_ele = $("#landline");
    var landlineNum = mobile_ele.val();
    var formattedNum = landlineNum.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{4})(\d{4})/g,"($1) $2 $3");
    mobile_ele.val(formattedNum);
});
```

Demo:https://jsfiddle.net/7c0d418t/

Answer (score 3):

I came up with 1 solution, not convinced how optimal it is, but someone may want to elaborate on it.

```
    function validatePhoneNumber(phone_number){
        var formatted = "";
        //remove all non-digits
        phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\D/g,'');
        //if number starts with 61, replace 61 with 0
        if (phone_number.match(/^61/)){
              phone_number = "0"+phone_number.slice(2);
        }

        if (phone_number.match(/^04/)){
            if (phone_number.length === 10){
                var formatted = phone_number.replace(/(\d{4})(\d{3})(\d{3})/g,"$1 $2 $3");
            } else {
                alert('Invalid phone number');
            }
        } else if (phone_number.match(/^02|03|07|08/)){
            if (phone_number.length === 10) {
                var formatted = phone_number.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{4})(\d{4})/g,"($1) $2 $3");
            } else {
                alert('Invalid phone number');
            }
        } else if (phone_number.length === 8){
            alert('Please use Area Code for landline numbers');
        } else {

            alert('Invalid phone number');
        }
        //update
        $("#phone").val(formatted);
    }
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/kb4u536a/

Answer (score 1):

You can find here phone validation code for more than 200 countries: [`https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber`](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber)